Azure function logs are showing up locally but not in application insights
I've done some research and the log level information should be sufficient to ensure the logs show up in application insights but they are not.
This post appears to offer an answer but does not seem to be a solution for my issue at a closer look: logs not appearing in Application Insights for Azure Functions v4 with .NET 8
Here is the host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.MyFunction": "Information",
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}

It seems like this should be a simple fix though I have not been able to locate the right information so far.

Did you define instrumentation key in app settings? Also did you do the same on Azure?

APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING has a value in environment variables but the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY is currently blank. Though based on research the connection string is now the preferred: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/migrate-from-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings

Right, i meant whether you have connection's info in place :)

This is still an active issue. Please provide additional information.

Use the provided code snippet to your program.cs file. This code configures your function app to send telemetry data (including logs) to Application Insights.
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        s.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        s.AddSingleton<IHttpResponderService, DefaultHttpResponderService>();
        s.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            // The Application Insights SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ILogger to capture only Warning and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.
            // Log levels can also be configured using appsettings.json. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs
            LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

If you want to capture specific log levels for individual functions, you can use the host.json file. The provided code snippet shows an example of setting the log level to "Information" for a function named "<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>".
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>": "Information",
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}

